# Windows 7 Professional Taskbar Grouping Disappears (Not using Aero Theme)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

I like using the grouping function with Windows 7, yes our company is still on Windows 7.  However, when using Outlook 2007, ("yes 2007") and excel 2007 when I have multiple emails or excel files open and begin closing files the grouping pop goes away.  This does not happen in Word 2007.  I was wondering if there is a registry setting or something to prevent this from happening.  I do not want to ungroup the task bar.

When I click on the "x" the grouping closes, but with Chrome and other applications it does not.  I would want the Grouping window to remain open so I can close all the sub items without the need to click on the Outlook Icon again.

[image: Outlook Grouped Files]

Comment: Are your taskbar properties set to "Never combine"?

Comment: Always combine, hide labels

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Do you want all instances of a program in one taskbar icon or each individually?

Comment: They are all currently combined.  The problem is that when you click on the task bar and pops up all the instances such as chrome you can close and the popup will remain open, but in Outlook and Excel when you close an instance the popup closes and does not remain open.  Then you have to click on the task bar again and close another then repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. Unfortunately, it is a little hard to picture, can you please provide some screenshots?